# Android app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest

Tags: android, gradle

I try to launch automatic test

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Rule public final ActivityTestRule<OrderManagementActivity> main = new ActivityTestRule<OrderManagementActivity>(OrderManagementActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void shouldBeAbleToLaunchMainScreen(){
        onView(withId(R.id.but_continue)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()));
   }

}
```

and I'm getting this execution failed for task.

> Error:Execution failed for task':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebugAndroidTest'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/junit/ClassRule.class

This is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xx.zakupy"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.1'

compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'

compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.7'

compile "org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6"
apt "org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6"

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:testing-support-lib:0.1'
}
```